# Java - return largest element in both arrays

Tags: java

I'm working on a program that returns the largest number that is in both arrays.  The following is some expectations:

```
 maxInCommon({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {-1, -2, 9, 5}) → 5  
 maxInCommon({1}, {}) → 0  
 maxInCommon({-1, -2}, {-2, -3, -4}) → -2
```

My code works for many situations, but not for this one:

```
asn9_maxInCommon({-10, -11}, {-10, -11, -12}) → -10
```

Instead of yielding "-10", my program returns a "-11".  The following is my UPDATED code:

```
public int maxInCommon(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) {
  int numInCommon = 0;

  Arrays.sort(nums1);
  Arrays.sort(nums2);

  ArrayList<Integer> nums1List = new ArrayList();
  ArrayList<Integer> nums2List = new ArrayList();

  int number = 0;
  int number1 = 0;

  for (int a = 0; a < nums1.length; a++)
  {
     number = nums1[a];
     nums1List.add(number); 
  }

   for (int b = 0; b < nums2.length; b++)
  {
     number1 = nums2[b];
     nums2List.add(number1);
  }

  for (int c = (nums1List.size() - 1); c > - 1; c--)
  {
     for (int d = (nums2List.size() - 1); d > -1; d--)
       {
           if (nums1List.get(c) == nums2List.get(d))
               numInCommon = nums1List.get(c);
       }
  }
  return numInCommon;
}
```

I thought the logic of the code should be fine, but it still does not work. Some other cases for which the logic fails are:

```
maxInCommon({0,2}, {0,1,2}) → 2
```

My code yields "0" instead.

```
maxInCommon({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {-1, -2, 9, 6, 7, 8, 9}) → 8
```

My code yields "6" instead.
The purpose of the ArrayLists is to somehow remove an element after each comparison.  I have not used that feature here.

Comment: you should change `numInCommon` only if the actual common value is bigger than the last common value found

Comment: Exactly. Just add a check to see if max1 == nums2[b] AND that max1 > numInCommon.

Comment: Thanks all, I'll look into each of your suggestions individually.

Comment: Once you get the brute-force algorithm to work, you should look into a faster implementation. I believe you can do an `O(m+n)` for this, where `m`, `n` are the sizes of the two arrays.

Comment: I'm sorting the two arrays in a ascending order, and making two loops that read from right to left, and comparing all numbers in nums2 against each in nums1.  Doesn't seem to work yet.

Answer (score 1):

the following works:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array1 = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
        int[] array2 = new int[]{-1, -2, 9, 5};
        System.out.println(getCommonMax(array1, array2));
    }

    static int getCommonMax(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
        int commonMax = 0;
        Arrays.sort(array1);
        for(int i = array1.length -1; i > -1; i--) {
            if(contains(array2, array1[i])) {
                commonMax = array1[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        return commonMax;
    }

    static boolean contains(int[] array, int i) {
        boolean contains = false;
        for(int i2 : array) {
            if(i2 == i) {
                contains = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return contains;
    }

}
```

Comment: to improve your code, you can traverse the array from right to left, so the first element found is the max common (the array is sorted from min to max)

Comment: but I am traversing the array from right to left; I didn't sort it in descending order, cause ascending is default and this makes it easier for the OP

Answer (score 0):

If your code actually works, you could change this part:

```
if (max1 == nums2[b])
    numInCommon = max1;
```

to

```
if (max1 == nums2[b] && numInCommon < max1) {
    numInCommon = max1;
}
```

that should do it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have `max1 = nums1[a];` in the outer `for` loop and then simply assign `max1` to `numInCommon` if `max1` is contained within the second array. `max1` is always going to be the last element in the first array, the `if` statement immediately after that is pointless.

Therefore the reason you get -11 as the largest number in common is because -11 is the last element in the first array, which is also in the second - that's what your function is computing.

You should instead be comparing if `max1` is greater than the largest number in common, and remove the unnecessary `if` statement from the outer `for` loop. A better name for `max1` is `temp`, and it's an unnecessary variable when you can just access `nums1[a]` from the inner `for` loop.

**EDIT:** Didn't see the homework tag, try and make the changes to the code yourself using the above information.

You should also probably have some way of indicating if there are no numbers in common between the two arrays.

Comment: Hi, I tested your code, and this is the test case: [link](http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7244/7034145105_1583017045_z.jpg).

Comment: I am wondering if I could find the largest number in the first array, compare it, then set it to 0, and repeat the same process, thereby finding the second largest number for comparison and so on.

Comment: @VũChâu: That's because `numInCommon` is initialised to 0 and 0 > 2. You should initialise `numInCommon` to the minimum int value or better yet use a `boolean` to indicate if any numbers in common have been found yet. I didn't fix the bug in the code because I just realised that this question was tagged as homework.

Answer (score -1):

Now its working fine.

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int a[] = {-1,-2};
        int b[] = {-2,-3,-4};

        try{
            System.out.println(getMaxCommon(a,b));
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Not found common no");
        }
    }

    public static int getMaxCommon(int[] arr1,int[] arr2) {

        int arr1Temp[] = arr1.clone();
        int arr2Temp[] = arr2.clone();

        Arrays.sort(arr1Temp);
        Arrays.sort(arr2Temp);

        List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int i=0;i<arr1Temp.length;i++){
            list1.add(arr1Temp[i]);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<arr2Temp.length;i++){
            list2.add(arr2Temp[i]);
        }


        if(arr1Temp.length < arr2Temp.length){
            for(int i=arr1Temp.length-1;i>=0;i--){
                if(list2.contains(arr1Temp[i])){
                    return arr1Temp[i];
                }
            }
        }else{
            for(int i=arr2Temp.length-1;i>=0;i--){
                System.out.println();
                if(list1.contains(arr2Temp[i])){
                    return arr2Temp[i];
                }
            }
        }

        return (Integer) null;
    }
}
```

Comment: He wants the maximum of the intersection of two arrays, not the maximum of one array.

Comment: So if I had `{4, 1}` and `{3, 2, 1}`, with return values of 4 and 3, how would I work out that the largest number in common was 1?